# Generating pdf using “PDFGenerator” in swift

Tags: swift, scrollview

In my swift application I am  generating pdf using “PDFGenerator”. When I am clicking the submit button, the pdf is generated successfully but the screen is getting blank.In this image there is a scrollview. The content view is on scrollview. But the submit button and the top image with back button is on the view(superview).

```
  func saveDataAsPdf() {
         let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
               let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
               let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("patientPdf.pdf")
               do {
                   try PDFGenerator.generate(scrollView, to: pdfPath)
                  
               } catch (let error) {
                 
               }
    }
```

**Image1-**

[image: Actual image]

When i am clicking on the submit button, the page is blank like this image.

**Image2-**

[image: image after generating pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Try amending this line:

```
try PDFGenerator.generate(scrollView, to: pdfPath)
```

to

```
try PDFGenerator.generate(PDFPage.pages(scrollView, configuration: PDFPagedScrollViewConfiguration(overlapPercentage: 0, ratio: .dinA4)), to: pdfPath)
```